# Set height of the floated div to fill area under it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have many DIVs in my content div, some of them float right and some float left on screen larger than 400px.

Working fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/cmbpt1hd/

I want height of area-three so that it fills all area under it on screens larger than 400px

Keep in mind

1. There may be many DIVs above area-three that float right.
2. There may be many DIVs in content div that float left.

**CSS solution will be preferred.**

**My code**

```css
#content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

.area-one {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #ffa2a2;
  padding: 8px;
}

.area-two {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #a4dca4;
  padding: 8px;
}

.area-three {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #8282ff;
  padding: 8px;
}

#footer {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff8282;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .area-one,
  .area-two,
  .area-three {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

  <div class="area-one">
    Area-one, Area-one.
  </div>

  <div class="area-two">
    Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two,
    Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two.
  </div>

  <div class="area-three">
    Area-three, Area-three.
  </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">
  Footer, Footer, Footer.
</div>
```

**Here is what I want**

[image]

Comment: You can use in this case clearfix on pseudo elements :after wich has as display table

Comment: are you looking for old browser support as well?

Comment: @NoobEditor No, but it will be better to have maximum support.

Comment: and all the data is dynamic in nature, no `div` height is know...right?

Comment: Yes, all the data is dynamic, even number of divs may vary.

Comment: thank you @fefe for very good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at flex-box, and splitting your HTML up so you have the left-side divs and the right-side divs wrapped in their own divs:

If you wrap your floating divs you don't have to give each of them a width and a float, and you can more freely add new divs.

Flex-box is great for filling out empty space or making divs distribute evenly.

```css
#content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
}
.area {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  float:left;
  clear:left;
  width:100%;
  padding: 8px;
  flex-grow:1;
}
.area-one {
  background-color: #ffa2a2;
}
.area-two {
  background-color: #a4dca4;
  flex-grow:0;
}
.area-three {
  background-color: #8282ff;
}
#footer {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff8282;
}

.float-left {
  width:70%;
}

.float-right {
  width:30%;
}

.float-box {
  display:flex;
  float:left;
  flex-direction:column;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .float-left, .float-right {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  #content {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="float-box float-left">
    <div class="area area-one">
      Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. Area-one, Area-one. 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="float-box float-right">
    <div class="area area-two">
      Area-two, Area-two.
    </div>

    <div class="area area-three">
      Area-three, Area-three.
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">
  Footer, Footer, Footer.
</div>
```

Comment: thank you @rblarsen for answer, what if screen size is less than 400px, please check output of my code.

Comment: I have updated my answer to make the divs be below each other when the screen is below 400px :-)

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` solution:

```js
function getHeight() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 400) {
    var areaOne = $('.area-one').height();
    var areaTwo = $('.area-two').height();

    var h = areaTwo - areaOne;
    $('.area-three').css('minHeight', h);
  } else {
    $('.area-three').removeAttr('style');
  }
}

getHeight();
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  getHeight();
});
```

```css
#content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

.area-one {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #ffa2a2;
  padding: 8px;
}

.area-two {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #a4dca4;
  padding: 8px;
}

.area-three {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #8282ff;
  padding: 8px;
}

#footer {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff8282;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .area-one,
  .area-two,
  .area-three {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">

  <div class="area-one">
    Area-one, Area-one.
  </div>

  <div class="area-two">
    Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two,
    Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two, Area-two.
  </div>

  <div class="area-three">
    Area-three, Area-three.
  </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">
  Footer, Footer, Footer.
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmbpt1hd/3/)**

Comment: height of area-three must be set back to normal for screens < 400px